# Permission denied while Saving file in external storage

Tags: java, android, android-external-storage

My goal is to copy an image file from the internal storage (data/data/myproject/...) to the external storage (the gallery). I just list a code example:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    private static final int REQUEST_CODE = 1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


    public void openActivity(View view){
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        intent.setType("image/jpeg");
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,"Select iamge"), REQUEST_CODE);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
            String image_path = getRealPathFromUri(this, data.getData());
            File externalInput = new File(image_path);
            File internalCopy = new File(getFilesDir(), temp_image.replace(".jpg", ".OUT.jpg"));
            File externalCopy = new File(image_path.replace(".jpg", ".OUT.jpg"));

            try {
                copyFile(new FileInputStream(externalInput),new FileOutputStream(internalCopy));
                System.out.println("Copied into internal Storage OK");
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                System.out.println("NOT Copied into internal Storage ERR");
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


            /* here some image manipulation are performed */



            if(!externalCopy.getParentFile().exists()){
                externalCopy.getParentFile().mkdirs();
                System.out.println("Created directories ...");
            }else{
                System.out.println("Directories already OK");
            }

            try {
                copyFile(new FileInputStream(internalCopy),new FileOutputStream(externalCopy));
                System.out.println("Copied into external Storage OK");
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                System.out.println("NOT Copied into external Storage ERR");
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
                System.out.println("NOT Copied into external Storage ERR");
            }
        }

        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }

    public void quitActivity(View view){
        android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
        System.exit(1);     
    }

     public static String getRealPathFromUri(Context context, Uri contentUri) {
            Cursor cursor = null;
            try {
                String[] proj = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
                cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(contentUri, proj, null, null, null);
                int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
                cursor.moveToFirst();
                return cursor.getString(column_index);
            } finally {
                if (cursor != null) {
                    cursor.close();
                }
            }
     }

     public void copyFile(InputStream in, OutputStream out) throws IOException {
         byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
         int read;
         while((read = in.read(buffer)) != -1){
           out.write(buffer, 0, read);
         }
     }

}
```

In this way the copy file is not copied for permissione denied! If I try externalCopy.getParentFile().canWrite() the result is false.

Please find following the LogCat output:

```
12-01 22:02:02.271: D/ActivityThread(22255): setTargetHeapUtilization:0.25
12-01 22:02:02.271: D/ActivityThread(22255): setTargetHeapIdealFree:8388608
12-01 22:02:02.271: D/ActivityThread(22255): setTargetHeapConcurrentStart:2097152
12-01 22:02:02.601: I/dalvikvm(22255): Could not find method android.view.ViewGroup.onNestedScrollAccepted, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onNestedScrollAccepted
12-01 22:02:02.601: W/dalvikvm(22255): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 11385: Landroid/view/ViewGroup;.onNestedScrollAccepted (Landroid/view/View;Landroid/view/View;I)V
12-01 22:02:02.601: D/dalvikvm(22255): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0000
12-01 22:02:02.601: I/dalvikvm(22255): Could not find method android.view.ViewGroup.onStopNestedScroll, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onStopNestedScroll
12-01 22:02:02.601: W/dalvikvm(22255): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 11391: Landroid/view/ViewGroup;.onStopNestedScroll (Landroid/view/View;)V
12-01 22:02:02.601: D/dalvikvm(22255): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0000
12-01 22:02:02.621: I/dalvikvm(22255): Could not find method android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.stopNestedScroll, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.setHideOnContentScrollEnabled
12-01 22:02:02.621: W/dalvikvm(22255): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 8963: Landroid/support/v7/internal/widget/ActionBarOverlayLayout;.stopNestedScroll ()V
12-01 22:02:02.621: D/dalvikvm(22255): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x000e
12-01 22:02:02.661: I/dalvikvm(22255): Could not find method android.view.ViewGroup.onRtlPropertiesChanged, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar.onRtlPropertiesChanged
12-01 22:02:02.661: W/dalvikvm(22255): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 11388: Landroid/view/ViewGroup;.onRtlPropertiesChanged (I)V
12-01 22:02:02.661: D/dalvikvm(22255): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0007
12-01 22:02:02.671: I/dalvikvm(22255): Could not find method android.content.res.TypedArray.getChangingConfigurations, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.TintTypedArray.getChangingConfigurations
12-01 22:02:02.671: W/dalvikvm(22255): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 366: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getChangingConfigurations ()I
12-01 22:02:02.671: D/dalvikvm(22255): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
12-01 22:02:02.671: I/dalvikvm(22255): Could not find method android.content.res.TypedArray.getType, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.TintTypedArray.getType
12-01 22:02:02.671: W/dalvikvm(22255): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 388: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getType (I)I
12-01 22:02:02.671: D/dalvikvm(22255): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
12-01 22:02:02.901: D/libEGL(22255): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_adreno200.so
12-01 22:02:02.941: D/libEGL(22255): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_adreno200.so
12-01 22:02:02.941: D/libEGL(22255): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_adreno200.so
12-01 22:02:02.941: I/Adreno200-EGL(22255): <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:299>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build: AU_LINUX_ANDROID_JB_REL_2.0.3.04.01.02.21.107_msm8625_JB_REL_2.0.3_CL3357771_release_AU (CL3357771)
12-01 22:02:02.941: I/Adreno200-EGL(22255): Build Date: 02/25/13 Mon
12-01 22:02:02.941: I/Adreno200-EGL(22255): Local Branch: 
12-01 22:02:02.941: I/Adreno200-EGL(22255): Remote Branch: quic/jb_rel_2.0.3
12-01 22:02:02.941: I/Adreno200-EGL(22255): Local Patches: NONE
12-01 22:02:02.941: I/Adreno200-EGL(22255): Reconstruct Branch: AU_LINUX_ANDROID_JB_REL_2.0.3.04.01.02.21.107 +  NOTHING
12-01 22:02:03.041: D/OpenGLRenderer(22255): Enabling debug mode 0
12-01 22:02:11.861: D/AbsListView(22255): Get MotionRecognitionManager
12-01 22:02:17.711: I/System.out(22255): Copied into internal Storage OK
12-01 22:02:17.711: I/System.out(22255): Directories already OK
12-01 22:02:17.721: I/System.out(22255): NOT Copied into external Storage ERR
12-01 22:02:17.731: W/System.err(22255): java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/sdcard0/DCIM/Camera/20141201_185225.OUT.jpg: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
12-01 22:02:17.761: W/System.err(22255):    at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:416)
12-01 22:02:17.761: W/System.err(22255):    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:88)
12-01 22:02:17.761: W/System.err(22255):    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:73)
12-01 22:02:17.761: W/System.err(22255):    at it.pittuzzo.fucre.MainActivity.onActivityResult(MainActivity.java:91)
12-01 22:02:17.761: W/System.err(22255):    at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:5387)
12-01 22:02:17.761: W/System.err(22255):    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3205)
12-01 22:02:17.771: W/System.err(22255):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3252)
12-01 22:02:17.771: W/System.err(22255):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1200(ActivityThread.java:143)
12-01 22:02:17.771: W/System.err(22255):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1289)
12-01 22:02:17.771: W/System.err(22255):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-01 22:02:17.771: W/System.err(22255):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-01 22:02:17.771: W/System.err(22255):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4960)
12-01 22:02:17.781: W/System.err(22255):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-01 22:02:17.781: W/System.err(22255):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-01 22:02:17.781: W/System.err(22255):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1038)
12-01 22:02:17.781: W/System.err(22255):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:805)
12-01 22:02:17.781: W/System.err(22255):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-01 22:02:17.781: W/System.err(22255): Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
12-01 22:02:17.781: W/System.err(22255):    at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
12-01 22:02:17.781: W/System.err(22255):    at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:110)
12-01 22:02:17.781: W/System.err(22255):    at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:400)
12-01 22:02:17.791: W/System.err(22255):    ... 16 more
12-01 22:02:19.761: I/Process(22255): Sending signal. PID: 22255 SIG: 9
```

Following the first rows of my ManifestActivity.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="it.pittuzzo.fucre"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="14"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
```

I'm working on real device: Mobile Samsung Core with Android 4.1.2 and Tablet Samsung Note 2014 Andorid 4.3.
It seems not related to the code because I copy/paste many examples found on the web and still the same result (can somebody try my code in order to check if the same result is faced?).

I really can't figure out...

Answer (score 0):

You can only use `openFileOutput()` for relative paths in intern memory. For external memory use `new FileOutputStream(..absolute..path..)`.

Comment: Thank you @greenapps for replying but following exception is raised:

`11-23 18:26:24.834: W/System.err(11553): java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/sdcard0/DCIM/Camera/20141123_151344.OUT.jpg: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)`

even if I unmount the device from the O.S. ...

Comment: Add the READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission?

Comment: Ok! I can't post the whole code, because it's gonna be very long (I skip Embed and Extract, because they have many dependencies).
My project export also the Java Build Path rt.jar (actually about that I'm facing some issue that I'm trying to solve, but it is related to the Embed and Extract classes, out of topic...).
Im going to edit the question!

However I set WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, should be implicit the READ too... am I right?
Thank you so much for helping @greenapps

Comment: Nonsense that it would be very long. Just a few lines more to see how you initialise file parameter. Now did you use FileOutputStream? If so then adapt the posted code please. And add the READ permission ofcourse.

Comment: You have an IllegalArgumentException in MainActivity.java:157. Which code is it?

Comment: Sorry @greenapps, just to make the topic more clear I edit the question in order to just focus on the issue. Because in the meantime I was working in the project and it is changing, so I just list a simple example which is not working :(

Comment: Just before try { copyFile. First check if the Camera directory exists and is writable. Like: File file = new File(location); if (!file.getParentFile().exists()){Toast(... file.getParent()..does nit exist); return}. if(!file.getParentFile().canWrite()) Toast(...).

Comment: I did! Everything seems perfect but still the exception, I wrote all the possible checks (see the edited code), the path in this way is changed, but same error ... :(

Comment: Well your code is a mess now. And you did not check the writability of f4. Instead you checked it for f3 which is not needed.

Comment: Ops.... Actually I thought all that checks helps :) And yes, I did mistake writing !f3.getParentFile().canWrite() instead of !f4.getParentFile().canWrite().... and YES, once I correct it, the output shows me that the directory where to copy exists but I cannot write there... what can I do? 
Thank you so much @greenapps!!!

Comment: You cannot do much for that. I suppose your device runs KitKat? Then no luck. Instead use getExternalFilesDir() as you can write there always.

Comment: Also try if getExternalFileDirs() -note the plural- delivers more dirs.

Comment: Noway! It gives me
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
:( with both (Dir and Dirs)...

Comment: I'm working on Android 4.1.2 (but I tried also on 4.3).
Using: 
File f4 = new File(getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES),"output.jpg");
the f4 absolutte path is the root
11-30 11:37:51.224: I/System.out(1844): starting...
11-30 11:37:51.234: W/ApplicationContext(1844): Unable to create external files directory
11-30 11:37:51.234: I/System.out(1844): /output.jpg

.... ???

Comment: The java.lang.IllegalStateException is raised if I run getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES) (caused by java.lang.NullPointerException)....

Comment: Of course. That is a wrong construct. Then you cannot use DIRECTORY_PICTURES.

Comment: what I have to pass to the getExternalFilesDir()?

However I tried the example here http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html
And still no positive result... :(

Comment: There is no example on that page so i wonder what you did. You better had shown your code. But to keep it short: pass null as parameter.

Comment: I tried also with null. The same... It is related to the permission but I can't figure out! :( It seems clear for me that it is not related to the code itself but something else... but what???
PS. I was talking about the example under the public static File getExternalStorageDirectory () method in that page

Comment: Please adapt the code here with getExternalFilesDir so we can have a look. You are using devices? Not emulators?

Comment: Yes, Im using real device!

Comment: However getExternalFilesDir(null) gives me null. Also getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)... Instead Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES) gives me /storage/sdcard0/Pictures

Comment: Your code now makes absolutely no sense with a file chooser and temp_image ? and using getFilesDir(). A complete mess.

Comment: Why? It is how I'm using it, if you think it is wrong please can you explain me errors? I copy the selected file (x.jpg) from the chooser to the internal storage (that's why getFilesDir()), after some manipulation are performed (which I do not post here the code). So the last part where I have the Permission denied while copying into the external storage x.OUT.jpg

Comment: You are doing way too much. And you did not tell in the introduction that two copyFile()s were involved. You presented your problem as one copy from internal to external memory. Even now your post tells as much. Please make a button where in onClick you copy a file from internal to external memory. Post that code. Remove all other code. Use getExternalFilesDir(null).

Comment: getExternalFilesDir(null) gives me null...
Let's make it simple: I just need to select a image X.jpg in the gallery and save in the gallery a copy X.copy.jpg (No Manipulation):
I just remove the internal storage step and the same issue... :(

Comment: It is hard to believe that it gives null on those devices. Which target and min sdk?

Comment: Choose a picture from the gallery that is not on sdcard as apparently you are not allowed to write there. Pick it from external memory where your app can write.

Comment: That is no code issue. Just put some pictures on a different place with a file explorer. The gallery will find them. Then try again.

Comment: nothing... do u have suggestion about which path?
But did u try my code on your device and is it working?

Comment: Put pictures not on the microSDcard with a FileExplorer. I already suggested you to do so. Why ask again? No i did not try your code. And cannot believe that getExternalFilesDir delivers null.

Comment: I did already greenapps, maybe my previous message was not clear! And trust me it does for me... can you try my code please?

Comment: `FileNotFoundException: /storage/sdcard0/DCIM/Camera/20141201_185225.OUT.jpg: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)`. Was that path of the sdcard? If yes then show which path you used instead now.